# Avoiding Duplicates in Loop (inside other loops)

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a complicated trigger (a labor of love for over 2 years now).  I've recently discovered one of the problems in it.  It ends up with duplicate entries in "updateList" to apply to SF (recently bulkified it with help from StackExchange, thank you very much).

```
if(updateList.get((Account)accObj) == null )
{ // Avoid DUPES...
    updateList.add((Account)accObj);
}
```

The first line is not right.   The .add line is FINE.  How do I reference the accObj in the IF (or another way of doing this please??).   I thought this would be simple.  Silly me.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're best using a Map to avoid dupes, as you can easily check if the AccountId already exists as a key value in the Map.

```
Map<String, Account> updateMap = new Map<String, Account>{};

if(!updateMap.containsKey((String)accObj.get('Id')) //check that Acc Id not already added
{ // Avoid DUPES...
    updateMap.put((String)accObj.get('Id'), (Account)accObj);
}
```

Then when you want to update Accounts, use

```
Database.update(updateMap.values());
```

Comment: Thanks... going to try this ASAP, reading through it, it sounds very appropriate.  It will be nice to be able to be more of an Answerer as time goes on.... (smile)

Comment: Its only a matter of time :) Please try it, and feel free to reach out for any clarifications.

Comment: I had to add the third parenthesis on the first IF, no problem... but it's generating the following error:

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Incompatible key type Object for MAP<Id,Account> at line 591 column 17         ((( which is th e"updateMap...." lime of the IF in your logic )))   Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: `            if( !updateMap.containsKey(accObj.get('Id') ) )  
            { //check that Acc Id not already added
                updateMap.put(accObj.get('Id'), (Account)accObj);
            }

Comment: (I still don't know how to post code in Comments, sorry - it looks like crap)

Comment: try the edited solution. added casting to string.

Comment: Same exact error.

Comment: Wait, you put it on BOTH refs... standby...

Comment: Okay, that compiled(!).  I will do some testing to verify but seems good now.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In this case how to avoid duplicate:

Map> mapSectionAgreement = new Map>();

```
        // Listing Agreement Section Names in to Map
        for(OISP_Agreement__c argmnts:lstAgreement){

            //List<OISP_Agreement__c> sectionNamesList = mapSectionAgreement.get(argmnts.OISP_Agreement_Section__r.name);

            if(mapSectionAgreement.containskey(argmnts.OISP_Agreement_Section__r.name)){
                List<OISP_Agreement__c> sectionNamesList = mapSectionAgreement.get(argmnts.OISP_Agreement_Section__r.name);
                sectionNamesList.add(argmnts);
                mapSectionAgreement.put(argmnts.OISP_Agreement_Section__r.name,sectionNamesList);
            } 
            else{
                List<OISP_Agreement__c> sectionNamesList = new List<OISP_Agreement__c>();
                sectionNamesList.add(argmnts);
                mapSectionAgreement.put(argmnts.OISP_Agreement_Section__r.name,sectionNamesList);
            }
        }
```